# How to write OCUnit Test Case

Tags: iphone, testing, ocunit

I want to write unit tests using Apple's default SenTestingKit for the below method:

```
- (NSDictionary*)getValueTags {
    return _tags;
}

- (NSString*)getFlag {
    NSString* jo = @"";
    for (NSString* key in _tags) {
        jo = [jo stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"&", key, [_tags objectForKey:key]];
    }
    if ([jo length] > 0) {
        jo = [jo substringToIndex:[jo length] - 1];
    }
    return jo;
}
```

I used default SenTesting

```
    - (void)setUp
    {
        [super setUp];

        // Set-up code here.
    }

    - (void)tearDown
    {
        // Tear-down code here.

        [super tearDown];
    }

-(void)testValueTags{

}

-(void)testGetFlag{

}
```

I am new to writing TestCases,  I need some guideline for sample methods to write test cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test case has four distinct phases:

1. set up
2. exercise
3. verify
4. tear down

Some of these phases can be empty. For example, most tear down happens automatically if you use ARC.

When you're starting, don't put anything into the `setUp` or `tearDown` methods. Just write a single unit test. Here's a worked example. (I'm going to change the names, because Objective-C idiom is not to use the word "get". So instead of `getFlag` let's just call it `flag`.) I'm going to call the class `Example, and I'll use ARC. And I use the abbreviation "sut" for "system under test".

```
- (void)testFlagGivenOneEntry
{
    // set up
    Example *sut = [[Example alloc] init];
    [sut setTags:@{ @"key1" : @"value1" }];

    // execute & verify
    STAssertEqualObjects([sut flag], @"key1=\"value1\"", nil);
}
```

That's one test. Let's add another.

```
- (void)testFlagGivenTwoEntries
{
    // set up
    Example *sut = [[Example alloc] init];
    [sut setTags:@{ @"key1" : @"value1",
                    @"key2" : @"value2" }];

    // execute & verify
    STAssertEqualObjects([sut flag], @"key1=\"value1\"&key2=\"value2\"", nil);
}
```

At this point, we have duplicate code: the creation of the sut. Now we can promote the variable up to an instance variable of the class. Then we create it in `setUp` and destroy it in `tearDown`:

```
@interface ExampleTest : SenTestCase
@end

@implementation ExampleTest
{
    Example *sut;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    sut = [[Example alloc] init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    sut = nil;
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testFlagGivenOneEntry
{
    [sut setTags:@{ @"key1" : @"value1" }];
    STAssertEqualObjects([sut flag], @"key1=\"value1\"", nil);
}

- (void)testFlagGivenTwoEntries
{
    [sut setTags:@{ @"key1" : @"value1",
                    @"key2" : @"value2" }];
    STAssertEqualObjects([sut flag], @"key1=\"value1\"&key2=\"value2\"", nil);
}

@end
```

For a more involved example, see [Objective-C TDD: How to Get Started](https://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-tdd/).